# MVC Deploy Views missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

Please help me a bit...

I have a domain with a web page, coded and compiled in VS2013, works like a charm... Then I decided to add a database, so I wrote one (ms sql). However, later when I deployed the project I can only watch the _Layout.cshtml file online, **local everything looks perfect**. What might be the problem? I've tried re-order some settings and scripts, but without success. A supplementary question, can the Connectionstring cause this? I've been having some problems with that nasty row.

This is my connectionstring for deploy:

```
<add name="20066_name" connectionString="Data Source=name-20066.mssql.domainaddress.com;Initial Catalog=20066-name;Integrated Security Info=True;User Id=secret;Password=secret" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So locally works fine with a local database, or using the connection string's remote database?

Try using the remote connection string with the local deployment and see if it connects. If it does, then you need to check the properties on the publish dialog. There is an option for altering the connection strings when you deploy (you might have heard this process as web.config transformation), so make sure that you send the correct connection string to the remote web server.

The connection string seems ok. You can experiment with more options though. Check the following link for ideas http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Local works fine with local connectionstring, everything looks great. After deploying with the new remote connectionstring, I can only view _ViewStart.cshtml, and that take about 10 seconds to load.. a few bytes.. I'll look more into this and the url you posted, thanks. By the way, I know nothing about altering the connectionstrings, but I'll look into that.

Comment: okay cool. You can also try connecting to the remote database from your computer, using visual studio or sql server studio and see if it responds. Maybe you need to set a different port or you need to contact your hostring provider for any extra settings or steps needed.

Comment: All firewalls disabled, did not manage to connect to the "host" from within VS2013 and MSSMS. There are far to many things that can be wrong here.. Ill look into this later. Thanks again @DrinkBird

Comment: I believe the problem is that my coding tries to connect to my local database. I tried to add it again with the same name as my online database name that I were given by my host. But VS2013 always change that name by adding an underscore at the beginning to every name i test. And I can't upload any code that ain't built. So in other words, I can't replicate the database name given to me by my host.